# Adjustment for hamburger toogle in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I just wanna ask how can I adjust the hamburger toggle for my WordPress navigation bar when it reaches a certain length it will act. I do aware hamburger toggle will happen by the default length itself but right now it happens to be my navigation bar have a lot of navigation and it looks off when it turns it to Ipad responsive design. The image below will be the interface that I got in at my navigation bar.

[image: navigation bar that has the responsive issue on my website]

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution to the issue. It just me over complicated for the options and thought to have modified from CSS. The solution here can be done through **Appearance -> Customising -> Header -> Mobile Menu (Mobile Menu Breakpoint)**. From there you can set the pixels you wanted to take effect of the "hamburger icon". Cheers.